# Update a value in a table using checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in php and I have a problem regarding checkbox.

First thing is that, in the form I don't know if name=medID[]  is specifically used as an array. or a normal string like medID will work? and how exactly is it useful to use an array.?

When I'm updating the value in query both $quan and $medID values are not passing in the query. 
  In browser it shows "Alloted Succesfully" but the database value of quantity is not changing. when i replace $quan and $imp value to some integers then it works fine.

```
<tbody>
                   <tr>

                    <form method="post" action="ytube.php?array=hospitalstock&hospitalID=<?php echo $opened['hospitalID']; ?>&id=allot" role="form"> 
                    <div class="form-group">            
                        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" name="medID[]" id="check" value="<?php echo $list['medID']; ?>" /></td>  
                    </div>
                        <td><?php echo $list['item']  ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $list['price']  ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $list['quantity']  ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $list['subtotal']  ?> </td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"  class="form-control" /> </td>
                    </div>




                     </tr>  

                    <?php }} ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Allot Medicine" name="submit" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    </form>                        


            </tbody>



        </table>  

        <?php 
            $id=$_POST['medID'];    
            $quan=$_POST['quantity'];

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if(empty($id) || $id==0){
                    echo 'Select medicines to allot ';
                }else{
                    echo $quan;
                    $imp= implode(", ",$id);

                    $q="UPDATE hospitalstock SET quantity= (quantity - '.$quan.') WHERE medID IN('.$imp.')" ;
                    $r=mysqli_query($conn, $q);

                    if(isset($r)){
                        echo 'Alloted Succesfully';
                    }

                }
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293226/how-to-update-a-mysql-column-based-on-a-checkbox-input
This may help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a normal string like madID will work just aswell.

- `name="medID"` =>  `$_post['medID']`
- `name="medID[]"` =>  `$_post['medID'][0]` de last `[0]` will get you the first element of the array

An array could be really helpful when it's a dynamically created form. A form where the number of inputs is not set, for example a contact form where you can click on a plus icon to add another text input for multiple phone numbers. Bacause its unknown how many phone numbers someone have its easier to just retrieve one variable as an array and iterate over this array after.

Don't you get an error like:

> Notice: Undefined index: medID in ....

In your code you have `name="medID[]"` and `$_post['medID']`. So your form is sending an array but you retrive a normal variable. Just delete `[]` from `name="medID[]"`

Because of that `if(empty($id)` $id will always be empty so you don't even reach your query.

Comment: I didn't get any such error. Also i made the change as you said. but i'm still not getting any result.    when i'm replacing $imp to $id, i'm able to make changes only for the last row in the table.  Maybe the problem is in storing the values. But i'm still not getting any result to update other rows.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to say; first I don't understand the concept of using a query string for `action` when you are using `post` as a `method` for submitting the values. Secondly if you are trying to consume the values from the query string as well; then I can't find the `$_GET[]` in your entire program. Third is a suggestion to use `$_REQUEST[]` when you are not sure about the get or post collections. Also, the `name="medID[]"` won't create any array for PHP. Is the `ytube.php` the same page where you have created this form?

Comment: `name="medID []"` Will created an array when retrieved `$_GET['medID']`

Comment: Well...I was meaning to say that if one value is needed at the time then there's no need to create an array like this. And also, there's only `$_POST` which I can see in the code.

Comment: @RaviGauravPandey This isn't the complete code. I used $_GET to get into this particular form page. And yes there is a need of using an array to pass each value,

Comment: @PHPeter Now i can get all the medID value. but now i'm facing problem to get the quantity value. i don't know how to get the value in query for the particular checked row.

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar now that is OK with medID. But do you want to update a single quantity value for all the medID values by using this query : `$q="UPDATE hospitalstock SET quantity= (quantity - '.$quan.') WHERE medID IN('.$imp.')" ;`
because for the query, this will put only a single value of entered quantity as `$quan` for every medID